# Issue with nested .each() loops in jQuery executing asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two nested each loops like so.

```
    $.each(a, function(index1, value1){
        console.log(value1)
        $.each(b, function(index2, value2){
             console.log(value2);
        }
    }
```

The output I'm expecting is

```
    a0
    b0
    b1
    b2
    a1
    b0
    b1
    b2
    etc
```

But what I'm actually getting is

```
    a0
    a1
    a2
    b0
    b1
    b2
    etc
```

How do I achieve the output I want. I understand that deferred objects are implemented now and that I can define functions and execution using deferred objects on functions I declare but I'm unsure on how to do that on existing functions.

EDIT: I messed up and abstracted it too much.

```
getAByX(x, function () {
            $.each(A, function (index, value) {
                full_list += "string with info";
                full_list += table_header;
                getBByA(value, function () {
                    $.each(B, function (index2, value2) {
                        full_list += "string with info";
                    });

                });

            });
            $(".table").append(full_list);
            hideLoading();
        });
```

Here's the trimmed full code, it's the function calls that are messing things up, $.each loops execute synchronously.

EDIT 2: Fixed the errors in the original short piece of code. Also, since the first piece of code works that means that the $.each loops execute synchronously and it's the function calls that I made that execute asynchronously. This realization makes the initial question invalid since the $.each call has the appropriate behavior.

Comment: You have to add more context to your problem. What code are you running... is it an ajax call?

Comment: post a fiddle if possible.

Comment: index and value of the second "each loop" should be renamed as they are already defined in the outer "each loop".

Comment: As the question stands right now, it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/989kj4Ly/

Comment: Yep, I abstracted the code too much, I've edited it to give a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is messed up. Here's the issue:

```
$.each(a, function(index, value) {
    console.log(a)
```

Notice you're printing `a`, not `value`. You're printing the value of the entire array each time through the loop, not the item you're iterating over.

This has nothing to do with deferreds or asynchrony.

Answer (score 1):

You should print `value` instead of `a` and `b`.

```
var a = ['a0', 'a1', 'a2'];
var b = ['b0', 'b1', 'b2'];
$.each(a, function(index, value){
    console.log(value) //console value instead of a
    $.each(b, function(index, value){
        console.log(value); //console value instead of b
    });
});
```

Also can try using `map()`.

```
a.map(function(val, ond){
    console.log(val);
    b.map(function(v, k){
        console.log(v);
    });
});
```